# SQL query to get the latest action/update on a specific object

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that contains the audit history of items, every modification made by a person will create a data event/row in the database, and the table will store every single modification from the first time that the item was edited to the latest time. If an item was modified 5, it will have 5 rows of data that will show for example the date-time, the item name, item ID, who edited, ...

Now, I need to extract just one and only the latest modification of that item. I tried to use a sub-table that will order the update time by descending, but when I join them together, they will show every single modification of that item from the first time to the latest.

Please could anyone help me out to extract just the exact latest action/modification? Much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? In SQL Server, we would typically use a ROW_NUMBER() function. Pseudo-code would be something like `ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID, ORDER BY EditDate DESC) AS rn`. This can be used in a temporary table or common table expression, and will add a rn column ordered by EditDate in descending order (meaning latest will get rn = 1, the one before that rn = 2, etc) per ItemId (and additional columns can be added in case of composite keys). You can then do a select on that temporary table `WHERE rn = 1`, and JOIN to the table based on ItemID and EditDate.

Comment: Thank you so much SchmitzIT, I've finally figured it out thanks to your suggestion. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. If you accept it, then it will help future visitors to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, we would typically use a `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Pseudo-code would be something like:

```
ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID, ORDER BY EditDate DESC) AS rn
```

This can be used in a temporary table or common table expression, and will add a rn column ordered by EditDate in descending order (meaning latest will get rn = 1, the one before that rn = 2, etc) per ItemId (and additional columns can be added in case of composite keys). You can then do a select on that temporary table `WHERE rn = 1`, and JOIN to the table based on ItemID and EditDate.